# Guess the Number Game in Python

Tags: python, beginner, object-oriented, python-3.x, number-guessing-game

I have been using Python to learn programming, but I am just recently beginning to utilize classes. I have a basic game below. Please review and let me know what I should improve on.

```
import random

class Game:

    def __init__(self):
        self.winningNumber = random.randint(0,100)        
        self.humanGuess()

    def humanGuess(self):
        self.humanGuessNumber = int(input("Guess from 0-100"))
        self.comGuess()
        return self.humanGuessNumber
    def comGuess(self):
        self.comGuessNumber = random.randint(0,100)
        self.conclude()
        return self.comGuessNumber
    def conclude(self):
        if abs(self.winningNumber - self.humanGuessNumber)< abs(self.winningNumber - self.comGuessNumber):
            print("You win")
        else:
            print("You suck")


game = Game()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You defined the class `Game`. However, this is an extremely vague name. Even if you have already named your module something like `guessthenum`, you should still give the class a specific name. I would select `GuessTheNum` as the class name.

Next up, we have your initialization function:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.winningNumber = random.randint(0,100)        
    self.humanGuess()
```

Nothing much to talk about here, other than my minor nitpick that you should add a space after your commas. I do have something to talk about the `humanGuess` and `comGuess` functions:

```
def humanGuess(self):
    self.humanGuessNumber = int(input("Guess from 0-100"))
    self.comGuess()
    return self.humanGuessNumber

def comGuess(self):
    self.comGuessNumber = random.randint(0,100)
    self.conclude()
    return self.comGuessNumber
```

The problem with the `humanGuess` function is that it forces input to be passed using the `input` function. In my opinion, classes should not engage in any form of IO unless strictly necessary (for example, a class for reading files).

Following this change, there is no need to return anything from `humanGuess` and `comGuess`. After all, the data is stored in the class.

To fix these problems, I would change both all three functions to this:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.winningNumber = random.randint(0, 100)

def humanGuess(self, n):
    self.humanGuessNumber = n

def comGuess(self):
    self.comGuessNumber = random.randint(0, 100)
```

Next, the `conclude` function:

```
def conclude(self):
    if abs(self.winningNumber - self.humanGuessNumber)< abs(self.winningNumber - self.comGuessNumber):
        print("You win")
    else:
        print("You suck")
```

Once again, following the no IO rule, I restructured the function such that it would return a boolean value indicating if the player wins:

```
def conclude(self):
    return (
        abs(self.winningNumber - self.humanGuessNumber)
        < abs(self.winningNumber - self.comGuessNumber)
    )
```

Now that we've cleared up the functions, let's take a look at the whole class:

```
class GuessTheNum:
    def __init__(self):
        self.winningNumber = random.randint(0, 100)

    def humanGuess(self, n):
        self.humanGuessNumber = n

    def comGuess(self):
        self.comGuessNumber = random.randint(0, 100)

    def conclude(self):
        return (
            abs(self.winningNumber - self.humanGuessNumber)
            < abs(self.winningNumber - self.comGuessNumber)
        )
```

I find that the structure of this class is unwieldy. If I were to design a `GuessTheNum` class, I would have just a single `isWin` function. It would take in my guess, generate a computer guess, then tell me if I suck or not.

Here's the way I would have written the full program:

```
class GuessTheNum:
    def __init__(self):
        self.winningNumber = random.randint(0, 100)

    def isWin(self, n):
        self.humanGuessNumber = n
        self.comGuessNumber = random.randint(0, 100)
        return (
            abs(self.winningNumber - self.humanGuessNumber)
            < abs(self.winningNumber - self.comGuessNumber)
        )

gtn = GuessTheNum()
n = int(input("Guess a number from 0 to 100: "))
if gtn.isWin(n):
    print("You win")
else:
    print("You suck")
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

@jonrsharpe reminded me that I had a DRY violation: 0 and 100 was repeated in a few places. Here's the updated version:

```
class GuessTheNum:
    def __init__(self, lower, upper):
        self.lower, self.upper = lower, upper
        self.winningNumber = random.randint(self.lower, self.upper)

    def isWin(self, n):
        self.humanGuessNumber = n
        self.comGuessNumber = random.randint(self.lower, self.upper)
        return (
            abs(self.winningNumber - self.humanGuessNumber)
            < abs(self.winningNumber - self.comGuessNumber)
        )

lower, upper = 0, 100
gtn = GuessTheNum(lower, upper)
n = int(input("Guess a number from %d to %d: " % (lower, upper)))
if gtn.isWin(n):
    print("You win")
else:
    print("You suck")
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

@TheBlackCat gave a few suggestions and reminded me of the PEP style. This fixes another DRY with `random.randint`.

```
class GuessTheNum:
    def _gen_number(self):
        return random.randint(self.lower, self.upper)

    def __init__(self, lower=0, upper=100):
        self.lower, self.upper = lower, upper
        self.win_num = self._gen_number()

    def isWin(self, human_guess):
        com_guess = self._gen_number()
        return (
            abs(self.win_num - human_guess)
            < abs(self.win_num - com_guess)
        )

lower, upper = 0, 100
gtn = GuessTheNum(lower, upper)
n = int(input("Guess a number from %d to %d: " % (lower, upper)))
if gtn.isWin(n):
    print("You win")
else:
    print("You suck")
```

Comment: Feel free to ask me any questions.

Comment: You have `0` and `100` in three places - DRY!

Comment: @jonrsharpe Reminds me, I forgot to have the class take in an upper and lower bound. Fixed.

Comment: I would probably have a `_gen_number` method that generates a random number based on `self.lower`, and `self.upper`.  You could then call this to get `self.winningNumber` and `self.comGuessNumber`.  And I don't think `self.humanGuessNumber` and `self.comGuessNumber` need to be attributes of `self`, since they are never used outside of the `isWin` method.  They should probably be just variables in `isWin`.  Also, it would probably be good to have default values for `lower` and `upper`, such as `0` and `100`, respectively.

Comment: Also, the method and attribute names are not pep8 compliant.  They should be all lowercase, separated by underscores.

Comment: @TheBlackCat Damn, I've forgotten quite a bit of Python's code style. Thanks for the reminder.