# Python TKinter data entry window GUI for SQLITE3 table

Tags: python, object-oriented, gui, sqlite, tkinter

I would like to offer for review a simple tkinter GUI window in Python 3 to be used for data entry into an SQLite database table.  As a noob, this is my first attempt at OOP and my first experience with `tkinter`, therefore, I was hoping for a thoughough review before I got too carried away.

The script below builds a simple table `bar` in a sqlite database `foo.sqlite`.  This is for demo purposes.  In reality, the database schema would be built elsewhere.

An instance of the class `EntryWindow` provides the GUI for the window.  Upon initialization, the window will read the column names of the given table (`bar`) from the sqlite database (`foo.sqlite`) and the build TK labels from the column names as well as entry fields for each column.  Finally, there is a button added which, when pressed will get the values from the entry fields and add a row to the database.

There is obviously a lot of additional logic which needs to be added (*i.e.* some data validation, disabling fields for PK's where the database should be assigning the next value, *etc.*) but I am at a place where I feel like I need to check in before I start adding complexity to the design.  Here's the code:

```
"""
A simple TKinter GUI to enter data into a given table in a database.

This program will build a small sample table into a given database
and then build a simple TKinter window with label and entry widgets
for each column in the table.
"""
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import N, S, E, W
from tkinter import TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT, END, ALL


def main():
    """Main function for demo."""
    # define some variables for demo only.
    # In full app, these will come programmatically.
    db = 'foo.sqlite'
    tbl = 'bar'
    columns = 'ID integer primary key', 'bizz text', 'bam text'
    create_table(db, tbl, *columns)

    root = tk.Tk()
    demo_window = EntryWindow(root, *[db, tbl])
    root.mainloop()


# create a sample table for demo purposes only.
# in full app the database schema would be created elsewhere.
def create_table(database, table, *col_defs):
    """
    Insert a simple table into sqlite3 database.

    Args:
        database (string):
        Name of database function will be creating table in.

        table (string):
        Name of table to be created in given database.

        *col_defs (tuple of strings):
        A tuple of strings containing the SQL column definitions for the
        given table being created in given database.
    """
    stmnt = (('create table {}('+('{},'*len(col_defs))[:-1]+');')
             .format(table, *col_defs))
    with sqlite3.connect(database) as conn:
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute('drop table if exists {};'.format(table))
        c.execute(stmnt)
        conn.commit()


class EntryWindow(tk.Frame):

    """
    Provides a simple data entry window for a given table in given database.

    Automatically generates labels and entry fields based on the column
    headers for the given table.  Provides a button to submit the row of data
    into the table and a button to close window.
    """

    def __init__(self, master=None, *args):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.database = args[0]
        self.table = args[1]
        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):
        """Build the entry window."""
        self.master.title('Enter data into {}'.format(self.table.upper()))
        self.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S), padx=10, pady=5)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        def get_col_names(self):
            """Retrieve column names for given table in database."""
            with sqlite3.connect(self.database) as conn:
                c = conn.cursor()
                c.execute("PRAGMA table_info('{}')".format(self.table))
                # Currently only uses one value from returned tuple.
                # TODO: Add logic to utilize type, not null and PK fields.
                self.col_names = [x[1] for x in c.fetchall()]
            return self.col_names

        self.column_names = get_col_names(self)

        # Add a label and entry box for each column in table.
        # TODO: Add functionality to gray out primary key fields where the
        #       database should be assigning the next value.
        # TODO: Add some validation logic.
        self.item_entry = []
        for item in self.column_names:
            num = len(self.item_entry)
            # print(num, ' --> '+item)
            tk.Label(self, text=item).grid(row=num, column=0,
                                           pady=1, sticky=E)
            self.item_entry.append(tk.Entry(self))
            self.item_entry[num].grid(row=num, column=1, pady=1, padx=5)

        def add_item(self):
            """Get entries from input fields and insert into database table."""
            entries = [e.get() for e in self.item_entry]
            # Build the SQL statement
            stmnt = ('insert into {0}({1}) values ({2})'
                     .format(self.table, ','.join(self.column_names),
                             ':'+',:'.join(self.column_names)))
            # print(stmnt, entries)
            with sqlite3.connect(self.database) as conn:
                c = conn.cursor()
                c.execute(stmnt, entries)
                conn.commit()
            clear_fields(self)

        def clear_fields(self):
            """Clear fields of entry windo and return focus to first field."""
            for e in self.item_entry:
                e.delete(0, END)
            self.item_entry[0].focus()

        # Add button to submit user inputs into database.
        submit_button = tk.Button(self, text='Add Item', width=8,
                                  command=lambda: add_item(self))
        submit_button.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=E, pady=10, padx=1)

        # Add a cancel button which closes window.
        quit_button = tk.Button(self, text='Cancel', width=8,
                                command=self.quit)
        quit_button.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=10, padx=1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Some specific questions I have are:

- Is my class structure proper? As I mentioned above, this is my first venture into OOP, and I was a little unclear as to what functionality should be in the `EntryWindow` class and what should be upper level functions.
- I have read in multiple places on SE (like [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/87287/guess-the-number-game-in-python)) that caution against classes engaging in IO, which obvioulsy (I think?) doesn't apply to a gui class, but got me thinking,  should the database interactions (like the `get_col_names` method) be in a seperate database class?
- Something is screwey with the way I have the args defined for the `__init__` method.  I don't think I should be using *args notation here as: `def __init__(self, master=None, *args):` and instantiating like `demo_window = EntryWindow(root, *[db, tbl])`, but when I change them to explicit like `def __init__(self, database, table, master=None):` and instantiate like `demo_window = EntryWindow(root, db, tbl)` (which seems proper to me), I get an error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tk'`

Comment: Please keep in mind that you should not ask a question on Code Review @ SE to fix programming issues. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic (seeing your `Attribute Error`) this should be asked at http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: @R4PH43L The code for review does not throw the error.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things that need looking at.

There seems to be an error in the `def add_item` method. The 'Build the SQL' section joins sections for table, column names and new values from the entry boxes but the last two items in the .format method BOTH insert 'column_names' whereas I would expect the last one to be 'entries'.

You seem to have gotten confused with the use of `*args`.

In 'main' you have

```
create_table(db, tbl, *columns)
```

and

```
demo_window = EntryWindow(root, *[db, tbl])
```

The asterisks (i.e. `*`) is used in the method DEFINITION as a place holder for the arguments that may not appear in the method call. If they do appear then they will be accessible as a tuple in the body of the method definition.

So

```
create_table(db, tbl, columns)  # no *
```

would pass the columns list as the first item of the `*col_defs` in the create_table method and be accessible as

```
col_defs[0].
```

Also

```
demo_window = EntryWindow(root, [db, tbl])  # no *
```

would pass the database and table list as the first item of the `*args` in the `EntryWindow` method to be accessible as

```
args[0][0]
```

and

```
args[0][1].
```

Note the double indices. The first accesses the first item in the `*args` tuple (even if there is only one!) and the second accesses the item within your list.

You could change the call to

```
demo_window = EntryWindow(root, db, tbl)  # no list and still no *
```

and then use

```
args[0]
```

and

```
args[1]
```

as you have done but to access the items within the `*args` tuple not items within a list.